# Chai testing await/async arrow function with parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, try-catch, chai

I am trying to perform Chai testing on several functions and have hit a roadblock of sorts.  The particular function I am calling should throw an exception under certain conditions.  I set breakpoints and could see where it threw the exception but it never propagates out to the expect function.  I keep getting this error:

```
AssertionError: expected [Function] to throw 'InvalidInviteException: This is not a valid invite.'

Expected :"InvalidInviteException: This is not a valid invite."

Actual   :[undefined]
```

```
export const createInviteDomainOwner = () => {
    const inviteDomainOwner = async ({
      emailAddress,
      firstName,
      lastName,
      domainId
    }) => {
        try {
           throw new InvalidInviteException('This is not a valid invite.');
        } catch (e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }

    return {
        inviteDomainOwner
    }
}


it('invite domain owner', async function() {
    const {inviteDomainOwner} = createInviteDomainOwner();

    await expect(() => inviteDomainOwner({
        emailAddress: 'abc123abc@test.com',
        firstName: 'John',
        lastName: 'Doe',
        domainId: '1111-1111-1111-1111'
    }).to.throw(new InvalidInviteException('This is not a valid invite.'));
});
```

How should I organize my try/catch exception handling for this to work as expected?

Comment: It _doesn't_ throw an error, it returns a promise that gets rejected. Try using e.g. https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised/.

Comment: That did it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@jonrsharpe's suggestion is correct,
[chai-as-promised](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised/) will do this. I give you a fully working example.

> Chai as Promised extends Chai with a fluent language for asserting facts about promises.

```
import chai, { expect } from 'chai';
import chaiAsPromised from 'chai-as-promised';

chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

class InvalidInviteException extends Error {}

export const createInviteDomainOwner = () => {
  const inviteDomainOwner = async ({ emailAddress, firstName, lastName, domainId }) => {
    try {
      throw new InvalidInviteException('This is not a valid invite.');
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
  };

  return {
    inviteDomainOwner,
  };
};

it('invite domain owner', async function () {
  const { inviteDomainOwner } = createInviteDomainOwner();

  await expect(
    inviteDomainOwner({
      emailAddress: 'abc123abc@test.com',
      firstName: 'John',
      lastName: 'Doe',
      domainId: '1111-1111-1111-1111',
    }),
  ).to.eventually.rejectedWith(InvalidInviteException, 'This is not a valid invite.');
});
```

```json
"chai": "^4.2.0",
"chai-as-promised": "^7.1.1",
```